# Getting weird output while finding prime number in java

Tags: java

I have two methods to find out prime number in java method - 2 working fine but getting wrong output from method one, can any help me where i did wrong in logic. Thanks in advance

**My entire code**

```
package prepare;

import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Squar {
        //Method - 1 to find prime number
        boolean isPrime(int num){
            int exp = (int)Math.sqrt(num);
            for(int i=2;i<exp;i++){
                if(exp%2==0){
                    return false;
                }
            }return true;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        Squar s = new Squar();
        System.out.println("From M1 "+s.isPrime(num));
        scan.close();
        System.out.println("From M2 "+s.isPrimeNumber(num));
    }
    //Method - 2 to find prime number
    public  boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
        if(number == 1){
            return false;
        }
        if (number == 2 || number == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
        for (int i = 3; i < sqrt; i += 2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

for input : 63  actual out put would be false in prime number but getting
different output from method one
**output**

```
63
From M1 true
From M2 false
```

Comment: Your for-loop in Method 1 seems to not add in anything to your code (the if-statement does not change as the loop continues). Did you want it to be `if(exp%i==0){` ?

Comment: i did calculated modulus value using if condition if the condition true return false @codeer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `isPrime` function like this.

```
 boolean isPrime(int num) {
        int exp = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
        for (int i = 2; i < exp; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Because in if condition you are checking  `exp%2 == 0` . But this statement does not change when iterating on `i < exp`. So this logic should be on  with `num % i == 0`

Comment: Yes drowny it is working fine now. i am getting expected output thanks much bro

Comment: I'm glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

In `isPrime()` method, Shouldn't you be checking `num % i == 0` rather than `exp % 2 == 0`?

Comment: Still the same output after replacing num % 2 == 0 Mushif bro

Comment: Make it `num % i == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this line of your code

```
if(exp%2==0){
```

it should be `num % i`

Comment: Still the same output Tayal

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the culprit is 
    `if(exp%2==0){` 
and it is causing a problem while iterating `i<exp`.So you may want to tweak it to 
    `num%i==0`

I have tried to give a few other approaches to this issue.
I hope that would be helpful.

I think there is a reason that tempted you to use
    **(int)Math.sqrt(num);**

I have tried to elaborate it below.

Consider below 3 approaches.
All of them are correct but the **first 2 approaches** have some drawbacks.

**Approach 1**

```
boolean isPrime(int num) {
for(int i=2;i<num;i++) {
    if(num%i==0)
        return false;
}
return true;
}
```

**We have a scope to make it faster.**

Consider that **if 2 divides some integer n, then (n/2) divides n as well.** 
This tells us we don't have to try out all integers from 2 to n.

Now we can modify our algorithm:

**Approach 2**

```
//checks whether an int is prime or not.
boolean isPrime(int num) {
for(int i=2;2*i<num;i++) {
    if(num%i==0)
        return false;
}
return true;
}
```

*Finally, we know 2 is the "oddest" prime - it happens to be the only even prime number. 
Because of this, we need only check 2 separately, then traverse odd numbers up to the square root of n. 
I think this might have tempted you to use (int)Math.sqrt(num);*

**Approach 3**

```
//checks whether an int is prime or not.
boolean isPrime(int num) {
//check if num is a multiple of 2
if (num%2==0) return false;
//if not, then just check the odds
for(int i=3;i*i<=num;i+=2) {
    if(num%i==0)
        return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Hence, **we've gone from checking every integer (up to n to find out that a number is prime) to just checking half of the integers up 
to the square root**. 
Is it not an improvement, especially considering when numbers are large.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first algorithm is almost (replace %2 with %i) correct. I do not know the second algorithm, but i would definitely change it to this form:

```
public boolean isPrime(int n) {
   if (n <= 1) {
       return false;
   }
   for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
       if (n % i == 0) {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Not true, consider number 1 which is not a prime number. For loop will not execute and 1 will be marked as prime by returning true.